# In firebase functions:shell, encountering error: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm using Firebase 7.0.0. When using `firebase functions:shell`, I receive the following error whenever I try to `get()` a document or `listDocuments()` in a collection, with no further info: "Error: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant".  Note that all works fine when the same code is deployed to Firebase Cloud Functions.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin'
try { firebase.initializeApp() } catch ( error ) { }


exports = module.exports = functions.https.onRequest(
        async ( request: functions.https.Request, response: functions.Response ) => {
            if ( request.method === 'POST' ) {
                await firebase.firestore().collection( `users` )
                    .listDocuments()
                    .then( ( documents: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference[] ) => {
                            for ( const document of documents ) {
                                console.log( `Found ${document.id}`)
                            }
                            response.status( 200 ).end()
                        }
                    )
                    .catch( ( error: any ) => {
                            console.error( `List failed: ${error}` )
                            response.status( 405 ).end()
                        }
                    )
            }
            else {
                console.error( `Unexpected ${request.method}` )          
            }
        }
    )
```

What am I doing doing incorrectly?

Comment: I don't see in your code where you actually defined a function for deployment or emulation using the `firebase-functions` SDK.

Comment: It was a snippet. I've updated it to contain the whole block of code that was "deployed" successfully to Firebase Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. "Error: 400 undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with **error: invalid_grant"**.

in my case, the problem was from firebase.initializeApp()

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

There wasn't any problem when I was doing only one project, but it started to happen when I tried testing 2 firebase function projects.
**admin.credential.applicationDefault()** setting is only for one project configuration, so only one project will work and others won't work if you have more then 2 firebase fuctions projects with that setting.

So, to solve this problem

1. In the Firebase console, open Settings > Service Accounts.
2. Click Generate New Private Key, then confirm by clicking Generate Key.
3. Securely store the JSON file containing the key.

When authorizing via a service account, you have two choices for providing the credentials to your application. You can either set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, or you can explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code. The first option is more secure and is strongly recommended.

To set the environment variable:

Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key. This variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session, set the variable again.

Linux or macOS

> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/service-account-file.json"

windows with PowerShell:

> $env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\username\Downloads\service-account-file.json"

if you want to pass the path to the service account key in code.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com'
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0 is an official document link about Adding the Firebase Admin SDK to the server.

I hope it will help someone.